# Wordpress Themes Pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes

I'm developing a wordpress theme from a photoshop PSD file. The theme has multiple pages I'm trying to add. I've created a custom page template and that works fine, but the page has multiple content areas. It has three divs separated by borders. Right now if you add content on the edit page menu it just puts it all in the first container.

Is there a way I can make it so the user can edit and add content to all three content areas from the admin panel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, totally possible. Many themes support this. Look at: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/14/advanced-layout-templates-in-wordpress-content-editor/ and http://digwp.com/2010/03/wordpress-post-content-multiple-columns/

Comment: Very helpful that's just what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very useful plugin for this is also available.  It is called Page.ly Multiedit, and you can find it here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pagely-multiedit/.

More detailed instructions and examples can also be viewed here: http://blog.page.ly/multiedit-plugin/.

This will allow for adding multiple editable regions to page templates, and also add a tab for each editable region in the page editor.  I've used this multiple times and had great success with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes .. you can add multiple container to let user edit .. try this **Multiple content blocks** : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-content-blocks/

in future if you want more specific container editor maybe in sidebar , footer or slideshow image editor you can use this **Magic Fields**:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields/

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look to this article from David Hansen at

http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/14/advanced-layout-templates-in-wordpress-content-editor/

and also to this one

http://wpstorm.net/2010/04/editor-styles-custom-post-types-wordpress-3-0/

and finally there's a plugin called advanced custom fields that perhaps helps you can download it at advancedcustomfields dot com

Good luck
Mike